# Is there a MP3 specification available to the public?

Tags: signal-processing, mp3, standards, specifications

Since [patents expired](https://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/ff/amm/consumer-electronics/mp3.html) in 2017, I wonder if there are specifications of the MP3 audio format that have been made available to the public?

Unfortunately, access to the official [ISO/IEC 13818-3:1998](https://www.iso.org/standard/26797.html) standard is not free and therefore a bad basis for an open source project.

I found some documents, but none of them described the structure of the data frames in detail:

- https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/26901-mp3-file-structure-howto/ (Informal, incomplete)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3 (Header spec, but only informal description of frames)
- http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm (Covers header only)
- https://sourceforge.net/p/lame/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/lame/libmp3lame/encoder.c#l244 (lame's code to encode a frame, not a spec)
- https://www.mp3-tech.org/ (Collection of papers mainly focused on how to enhance encoding)
- https://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/docs/mp3_theory.pdf (Description of frame layout and header, but no in-depth description of frame's *Main Data*)

Of course one could reverse engineer a spec by analyzing open source MP3 en-/decoder, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

If you are curious what I need this for: I have some experience in signal processing and want to extend a program to do certain manipulations to MP3 files without re-encoding and the involved quality loss.

Comment: As far as I know, looking at the source of one of the open source codecs is the best right now.

Comment: @Brad I would really prefer not being the one who reverse engineers the spec =/

Comment: If I remember correctly, the spec provides a detailed description of how to *decode* MP3.   There's no single right way to encode to that format, and the best encoders are the result of much non-public research...  So maybe the spec is not what you are looking for even if it's publicly available.

Comment: @MattTimmermans thank you for the heads-up. However, I think the specs and the description of the decoding process should be sufficient for my purposes, or at least a good starting point.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to find it? I myself now is interested to find out how loudness level is encoded (e.g. is it some bit depth or floating point or ...).

Comment: @Alexei: unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Your linked mp3lame source in function lame_encode_mp3_frame function refers to a paper called "MPEG-Layer3 / Bitstream Syntax and Decoding" by Martin Sieler, Ralph Sperschneider. That paper has quite detailed information about the mp3 frames themselves. I found it on the internet:

https://mp3guessenc.sourceforge.io/MPEG%20Layer3%20Bitstream%20Syntax%20and%20Decoding.pdf

Here's a Web Archive link just in case: https://web.archive.org/web/20231125190134/https://mp3guessenc.sourceforge.io/MPEG%20Layer3%20Bitstream%20Syntax%20and%20Decoding.pdf

Comment: Both the document that you link to and its [associated program](https://mp3guessenc.sourceforge.io/) are superb - thank you so much for the pointer!